# Which SQL Server package is to be used for Mac?

Tags: mac, sql-server-2008

I want to install the SQL Server 2008 in my Mac machine. I have used the one appropriate for my Windows machine. Now I want to install into the Mac, so please suggest the appropriate software package for that.

I have searched in Google also and got some software package related for Mac.  Could I have the link for the SQL Server 2008 for Mac?

Comment: The software package is called *Windows*. You can install it on your Mac, replacing Mac OS X, or in a virtual machine product like Sun Virtualbox or VMware Fusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can [connect](http://www.razorsql.com/articles/sql_server_mac.html) from a Mac to a SQL server, but there isn't a version of it that runs on Mac, at least not to my knowledge.

Comment: **Microsoft** SQL server? I highly doubt there is.

Comment: @slhck I got burned searching for something on the net earlier, so I'm hedging my bets, but you're right.  Hehe, they do have Office for Mac.